# Confusing TypeError exception error message caused by wrong number of method arguments in python

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

Let’s code for example a class called `Rocket`:

```
class Rocket():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Created a Rocket called '" +  str(name) + "'!")

    def liftOff(self):
        print("10, 9 ,8 ,7 ... Lift Off!!")
```

and create an instance `SaturnV` of this class, but pass no arguments to the `__init__` method:

```
SaturnV = Rocket()
```

We produce a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    SaturnV = Rocket()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Why does the compiler print, that `__init__()` takes exactly **2 arguments** instead of **1 required `name` argument**?

Why do they not change the error message to something like...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    SaturnV = Rocket()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument in addition to the instance reference (0
           arguments given)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python counts the `self` keyword as an argument as well. That just means that it expects to be called on an class instance via the famous `.` (as in `satrurnV.name`)or you could optionally do a `getattr(saturnV, "name")` to retrieve the same thing.

The `__init__()` method is special because it gets called implicitly when you do `Rocket()` which is basically `Rocket.__init__()`. Now you see that the other argument, the one that you're missing is the `name`.

you also have an error in your code:

```
print("Created a Rocket called" +  "'str(name)'" + "!")
```

should be

```
print("Created a Rocket called" +  str(name) + "!")
```

`str()` function takes the object in the `()` and returns a string so there's no need to ut that under `" "`

Comment: @elegent: I'd like to quote the  Zen of Python. "Explicit is better than implicit.". Imagine if you had multiple instances of class, and you sent in the name, but called the method without the `instance.` what would you put the error report as?

Comment: @elegent You can't call a method without having an instance. method that doesn't need an instance is just a function. (that's why you have functions: `def func()` and methods `def method(self)`. You can have an unbound method of a class (i.e. `class Foo` under which you have `def unbound_method()`) but you still have to call `Foo.unbound_method()`. Idea of methods is that you can have various instances, with different attributes, on which you can do the same work (method), but get different results. If you want a method you don't have to call an instance of, use a function.

Comment: @elegent, because you don't always pass **the same** instance. You can create 7 different rocket instances and the result of your method liftOff would be `3..2..1 Rocket1 liftoff!`, `3..2..1 Rocket2 liftoff!`, `3..2..1 Rocket3 liftoff!` (i.e.), so the end result would be different for **each** of the instances. That's kind of the point of classes, to describe an abstract idea with a programing language, and to act on those abstract ideas and get a slightly different result each time, like a BMW would accelerate faster than Golf, but they're both cars.

Comment: @Ijetibo: Yah, I know the idea behind OOP, but I was confused by the error message.

 Thank you very much for your informative answer and comments. :)